# when will neo4j support dates as properties

Tags: neo4j

As an medieval historian i'm building graph-databases about informations from charters and other historical documents.

It would be very helpfull, to add dates as attributes as we often ask for documents from a specific time-range.

At the moment I'm using normalized data (YYYY-MM-DD) combined with regular expressions but the native support of date-informations (in a normalized way) would be very nice.

Greeting,
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Most people store date/time information using a long property holding the millisecs since epoch (aka `Date.getTime()`). This way you can do easily math and comparison with time information. 
In case you need a timezone, store the timezone name in an additional property.

Comment: It just occurred to me that he should make sure that the integer field is big enough to store the negative numbers he would need to store medieval dates.  Also, I would suggest always storing in UTC, though it seems like he's just dealing with dates.  Seeing how he's storing dates, maybe it would be simpler to have an integer representing the number of days ACE (positive) or BCE (negative)

Comment: Ahh, dates before 1970 are stored ad negative numbers ?

Comment: Depends on your implementation, I expect.  When try it in Ruby it gives me a negative number

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's answer is probably better than mine, though depending on what you're trying to do you might also want to consider a Date hierarchy as part of your graph.  For example you could have the following structure for

```
(:Year {text: '1227'})<-[:IN_YEAR]-(:Month {text: '1227-08'})<-[:IN_MONTH]-(:Day {text: '1227-08-18'})<-[:HAPPENED_ON]-(:Event {title: 'Death of Genghis Khan'})
```

Comment: looks interesting. As medieval historian we're dealing with dates all the time especially with timeranges. And when i export neo4j-data to Gephi i would like to use the gehpi-timeline.

Comment: do you think it could be possible to add all dates e.g. of the 14th century as nodes an then connect an charter-node to the corresponding date-node ?

Comment: You could probably store the date/time string as well as the tree structure.  Really, it depends on what you're trying to do.  I can't find the article now, but I saw an article describing how to do this and also put `NEXT` relationships in between subsequent day nodes to allow for better querying on ranges, but I'm not sure how that would work if your dates are sparse

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly possible.  (100 years * 365 days) + (100 years * 12 months) + (100 years) = 37,800 nodes total.  Wouldn't be too bad in my opinion.

Comment: You can use the GraphAware Timetree to help build the time structure and answer range queries. It will build portions of the tree on demand. http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html Disclaimer: I work at GraphAware